# Gallery will not display the full 950px width in Safari or Chrome. It looks normal on Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html

I've come across a bug. My Gallery displays normally on Firefox a it should, but on Safari and Chrome shrinks it. I'd like the gallery to display as the full 950px across the page.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#myGallery').galleryView();
    });
</script>

 <ul id="myGallery">
     <li><img src="images/IMG_8587.jpg" alt="The Pig &amp; Whistle SW18" />
        <li><img src="images/IMG_8495.jpg" alt="The Pig &amp; Whistle SW18" />
        <li><img src="images/IMG_8582.jpg" alt="The Pig &amp; Whistle SW18" />
        <li><img src="images/IMG_8491.jpg" alt="The Pig &amp; Whistle SW18" />
    </ul>
```

CSS for Gallery

```
#myGallery { display: none; top:0 auto; width:950px !important; float:none; }

.gv_galleryWrap { position: relative; background: #222; font-size: 10pt; padding: 0 5px 5px 5px !important;}

/* GALLERY DIV */
.gv_gallery { overflow: hidden; position: relative;}

.gv_imageStore { visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px; }


.gv_panelWrap { filter: inherit; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;}

.gv_panel-loading { background: url(img-loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #aaa; }
.gv_frame-loading { background: url(img-loader.gif) 50% 50% no-repeat #aaa; }

/* GALLERY PANELS */
.gv_panel { filter: inherit; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: 100; width:950px !important; }
.gv_panel img { position: absolute; width:950px !important; }

.gv_overlay { position: absolute; background: #222; color: white; z-index: 200; }
.gv_showOverlay { 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 20px; 
    height: 20px; 
    background: url(themes/light/info.png) #222; 
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 200;
}
.gv_overlay h4 { color: white; margin: 1em; font-weight: bold; }
.gv_overlay p { color: white; margin: 1em; }

.gv_infobar {
    background: #222;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 2000;

}



.gv_filmstripWrap { overflow: hidden; position: absolute; }


/* FILMSTRIP */
.gv_filmstrip { margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

/* FILMSTRIP FRAMES (contains both images and captions) */
.gv_frame { 
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* WRAPPER FOR FILMSTRIP IMAGES */
.gv_frame .gv_thumbnail { position: relative;overflow: hidden !important; }

/* WRAPPER FOR CURRENT FILMSTRIP IMAGE */
.gv_frame.current .gv_thumbnail {}

/* FRAME IMAGES */
.gv_frame img { border: none; position: absolute; }

/* FRAME CAPTION */
.gv_frame .gv_caption { height: 14px; line-height: 14px; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; color:white; }

/* CURRENT FRAME CAPTION */
.gv_frame.current .gv_caption { }

/* POINTER FOR CURRENT FRAME */
.gv_pointer {
    border-color: black;
}

/* NAVIGATION BUTTONS */
.gv_navWrap {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.gv_navPlay,
.gv_navPause,
.gv_navNext,
.gv_navPrev {

    opacity: 0.3;
    -moz-opacity: 0.3;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3;
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.gv_navPlay:hover,
.gv_navPause:hover,
.gv_navNext:hover,
.gv_navPrev:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
}

.gv_panelNavPrev,
.gv_panelNavNext {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.50;
    -moz-opacity: 0.50;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.50;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 200;
}

.gv_panelNavPrev:hover,
.gv_panelNavNext:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
    -moz-opacity: 0.9;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
}

.gv_navPlay {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/play-big.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.gv_navPause {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/pause-big.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.gv_navNext {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/next.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.gv_navPrev {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/prev.png) top right no-repeat;
}
.gv_panelNavNext {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/panel-next.png) top left no-repeat;
}
.gv_panelNavPrev {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(themes/light/panel-prev.png) top right no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You might want to make sure that your HTML is valid (you're missing closing `</li>` for example). Your problems may be due to Chrome "auto-fixing" your markup somehow.

Comment: _“you're missing closing `</li>` for example”_ – not necessarily, HTML5 allows to leave out ending tags as HTML 4.01 did.

Comment: @Cbroe ~ ah, cool. completely forgot about that, nice catch.

Comment: Avoiding the fact it's still allowed, and unrelated to the answer, it's bad practice! :)

Comment: Thanks guys. And @RichardNeilIlagan, unfortunately is not the closing <li>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed that `#myGallery` no longer exists after the plugin creates your gallery? Instead it's being replaced with a bunch of `.gv_gallery` and similar elements. (Unless I'm using the [wrong plugin](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/)?)

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdR3A/1/) for what you currently have, and
here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdR3A/2/) for the fix.

```
.gv_gallery, .gv_galleryWrap { width: 950px !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It still displays perfectly on firefox, however, safari still playing up. Here's a print screen. Thank you so much!
http://www.casasaocarlos.com.br/website_piggy/images/screenshot.png

Comment: This is how it looks in my Chrome as well (both Webkit). How is this not your desired behavior? Do you want the image to be centered?

Comment: Yes please. This is the desired look.
http://www.casasaocarlos.com.br/website_piggy/images/screenshot2.png

Comment: Is the image height important? Because basically you can just edit the image's CSS to fit the width (use width:100% or something). Unless you want it to crop when it's too high, which is a different approach. Tip: Use Chrome's inspector (or Firefox's Firebug extension) to get the image's ID/class quickly to use it as a CSS selector.

Comment: .gv_panelWrap { filter: inherit; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; width:950px !important;} fixed it. thank you